# How do I get rid of a 'settle blur' CSS effect

Tags: html, css

I currently have a tile on which I hover is initially blurred. After the image is zoomed out, this blur sort of settles down and produces an undesired effect on the tile. Please have a look at the code I have pasted. It should give you a fair idea of what I'm talking about.

I tried messing around with the CSS after and before the image is hovered upon but that doesn't change anything.

```css
.tiles {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    postiion: relative;
    margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
}

.tiles article {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(33.33333% - 2.5em);
    margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
}

.tiles article > .image {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tiles article > .image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.tiles article > .image:before {    
    -moz-pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-pointer-events: none;
    -ms-pointer-events: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1.0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.tiles article > .image:after {
    -moz-pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-pointer-events: none;
    -ms-pointer-events: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    opacity: 0.25;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tiles article > a {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 3;
}

    .tiles article > a > :last-child {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .tiles article > a:hover {
        color: #ffffff !important;
    }

    .tiles article > a h2 {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .tiles article > a .content {
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 0;
        line-height: 1.5;
        margin-top: 0.35em;
        opacity: 0;
    }

        .tiles article > a .content > :last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

    body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:before {
        background-color: #333333;
        opacity: 0.35;
    }

    body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:after {
        opacity: 0;
    }

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover .content {
    max-height: 15em;
    opacity: 1;
}

* + .tiles {
margin-top: 2em;
}

body.is-loading .tiles article {
-moz-transform: scale(0.9);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
-ms-transform: scale(0.9);
transform: scale(0.9);
opacity: 0.8;
}

body.is-touch .tiles article .content {
max-height: 15em;
opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

.tiles {
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
}

    .tiles article {
        width: calc(33.33333% - 1.25em);
        margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

.tiles {
    margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
}

    .tiles article {
        width: calc(50% - 2.5em);
        margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {

.tiles {
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
}

    .tiles article {
        width: calc(50% - 1.25em);
        margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
    }

        .tiles article:hover > .image {
            -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
            transform: scale(1.0);
        }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.tiles {
    margin: 0;
}

    .tiles article {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 1.25em 0 0 0;
    }

}
```

```html
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
      <section class="tiles">
     <article>
         <span class="image">
             <img src="http://cdn.iwillteachyoutoberich.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/generic-candy.jpg" />
         </span>
         <a href="#zaplan" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" target="_blank">
             <h2>IrackBot</h2>
             <div class="content">
                 <p>Featured on the official Slack website, IrackBot is built for for Efficient and Manageable Open Source communication across Slack and IRC 
                 </p>
                 <h3>
                 <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                 </h3>
             </div>
         </a>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
```

Do you notice the slight unblurring/settling down of the image after it is hovered upon and zoomed? I wish to get rid of that and keep it blurred.

Comment: I see overflow that's trimmed at the end of the transition. The solution might lie there.

Comment: Just so you know, that's a bug with Chrome. It doesn't happen on Firefox. Just add `filter: blur(5px);` along with the `-webkit-filter: `, and blur will work of FF35+ as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the blur on Firefox just add `filter: blur(5px);` along with the `-webkit-filter:`, and blur will work of FF35+ as well.

As for the unblurring that appears there, is actually a bug which happens on Chrome (and probably every other webkit browser). This doesn't happen on Firefox though.

So to fix it you need to add: `transform: translateZ(0);`, this will not cause any visual differences and will take care of the problem on Chrome.

```css
.tiles {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    postiion: relative;
    margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
}

.tiles article {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    position: relative;
    width: calc(33.33333% - 2.5em);
    margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
}

.tiles article > .image {
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.tiles article > .image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.tiles article > .image:before {    
    -moz-pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-pointer-events: none;
    -ms-pointer-events: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1.0;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.tiles article > .image:after {
    -moz-pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-pointer-events: none;
    -ms-pointer-events: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    opacity: 0.25;
    z-index: 2;
}

.tiles article > a {
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -moz-transform 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -webkit-transform 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.5s ease, -ms-transform 0.5s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 3;
}

    .tiles article > a > :last-child {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .tiles article > a:hover {
        color: #ffffff !important;
    }

    .tiles article > a h2 {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .tiles article > a .content {
        -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        -ms-transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        transition: max-height 0.5s ease, opacity 0.5s ease;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 0;
        line-height: 1.5;
        margin-top: 0.35em;
        opacity: 0;
    }

        .tiles article > a .content > :last-child {
            margin-bottom: 0;
        }

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px); /* firefox 35+ */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.1); /* Chrome fix - add translateZ */
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.1); /* Here as well */
}

    body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:before {
        background-color: #333333;
        opacity: 0.35;
    }

    body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover > .image:after {
        opacity: 0;
    }

body:not(.is-touch) .tiles article:hover .content {
    max-height: 15em;
    opacity: 1;
}

* + .tiles {
margin-top: 2em;
}

body.is-loading .tiles article {
-moz-transform: scale(0.9);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
-ms-transform: scale(0.9);
transform: scale(0.9);
opacity: 0.8;
}

body.is-touch .tiles article .content {
max-height: 15em;
opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {

.tiles {
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
}

    .tiles article {
        width: calc(33.33333% - 1.25em);
        margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

.tiles {
    margin: -2.5em 0 0 -2.5em;
}

    .tiles article {
        width: calc(50% - 2.5em);
        margin: 2.5em 0 0 2.5em;
    }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {

.tiles {
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -1.25em;
}

    .tiles article {
        width: calc(50% - 1.25em);
        margin: 1.25em 0 0 1.25em;
    }

        .tiles article:hover > .image {
            -moz-transform: scale(1.0);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.0);
            transform: scale(1.0);
        }

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.tiles {
    margin: 0;
}

    .tiles article {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 1.25em 0 0 0;
    }

}
```

```html
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
      <section class="tiles">
     <article>
         <span class="image">
             <img src="http://cdn.iwillteachyoutoberich.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/generic-candy.jpg" />
         </span>
         <a href="#zaplan" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" target="_blank">
             <h2>IrackBot</h2>
             <div class="content">
                 <p>Featured on the official Slack website, IrackBot is built for for Efficient and Manageable Open Source communication across Slack and IRC 
                 </p>
                 <h3>
                 <i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-lg fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                 </h3>
             </div>
         </a>
        </article>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: There's still an artifact in Chrome here, but much smaller

Comment: Thank you so much. The artifact is there but much more smaller and manageable I guess.